# How to change img data to img url while drag and drop to TinyMCE?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, tinymce

I've TinyMCE in my Wordpress blog (like all). When i drag and drop image from my computer disc to the TinyMCE window it is uploaded and embedded as img with data field. The effect of this is that after putting some images this way size of post is too big to be handled properly and saved by Wordpress.

Of course i know i can open the image upload window and drop image there but it would be so much easier if i could just drop the image like now: directly to the TinyMCE window and it would work like the drop box.

So basically what i imagine it should work like this: when i drop image to TinyMCE it gets the data of image, saves it to image folder of Wordpress and replace the img data to img url.

So... yeah... do you know any plugin that works that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plugin that i know of.

You will need this code to intercept the drop event

```
$(ed.getDoc()).bind('drop', function(event){

    // you can read out different flavours (html, plain, file, etc....)
     var drag_content_html = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
     var drag_content_plain1 = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');

}
```

Comment: This does not solve the entire problem. Users can also select copy from a context menu in their browser or other software and paste into wysiwyg editors. This causes MB's of image data because base64 encoding is up to 4 times bigger than binary data...

Comment: unfortunatly, context menues actions cannot be intercepted by javascript (but depending from the browser this is possible using an own browser AddOn)

Comment: I suppose we should capture the data and strip the "data:image/..." from the content

Comment: The `base64` encoding expands the file `8/6` times or about 33% increase, not 4x. That said, it's still a very poor idea to include files over a few kB as data URLs because those cannot be cached client side when the content is viewed again later. It seems that TinyMCE doesn't support this natively so you may need to accept the data URL into the editor and then extract the file data from the editor area and submit it to the server to get permanent URL for the data and then convert the data URL within the editor into a permanent URL reference by yourself.